# Does WPF provide a way to render the elements of a collection on a single Viewport3D using binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Note: I've omitted camera and light definitions in the XAML snippets to focus majorly on the real problem.

## The problem with WPF

I would like to bind an `ObservableCollection` to one of WPF's 3D classes (like `ModelVisual3D`) In a way similar to the following:

```xml
<Viewport3D>
    <Viewport3D.Children>
        <Some3DClass ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
            <Some3DClass.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- definition of the template -->
            </Some3DClass.ItemTemplate>
    </Viewport3D.Children>
</Viewport3D>
```

However, after some research and testing, I did not found anything similar in WPF.

## A solution (sort of) with Helix Toolkit

[Helix toolkit](http://www.helix-toolkit.org/) is a library that offers a set of 3D components for WPF. Also, I've discovered that one of the examples ([DataTemplate](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/develop/Source/Examples/WPF/ExampleBrowser/Examples/DataTemplate)) claimed to provide exactly what I needed.

#### How does it work?

Here is a similar implementation of the xaml part of the example:

```xml
<helix:HelixViewport3D>
    <local:ItemsVisual3D ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
        <local:ItemsVisual3D.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate3D>
                <CubeVisual3D Center="{Binding Position}" SideLength="3" Fill="OrangeRed"/>
            </DataTemplate3D>
        </local:ItemsVisual3D.ItemTemplate>
    </local:ItemsVisual3D>
</helix:HelixViewport3D>
```

This example works thanks to two classes:

- `ItemsVisual3D`: A class that extends `ModelVisual3D` to contain an `IEnumerable ItemsSource` dependency property. It also contains a `DataTemplate3D` to control the rendering of the single elements of the collection.
- `DataTemplate3D`: A custom template, deriving from `DispatcherObject` that defines that uses a `Visual3D` as the content property.

#### The issue

However, I've found a major problem: the `Center`s of the cubes were set correctly, but the other two properties, `SideLength` and `Fill` were not set at all, ending up with small blue cubes (by default) instead of bigger orange red cubes.

I've investigated a bit, and I realized that in [DataTemplate3D.cs](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/master/Source/Examples/WPF/ExampleBrowser/Examples/DataTemplate/DataTemplate3D.cs), only the bounded properties are set. I resolved the problem quickly, because there was a commented block of code in the function, that sets the properties defined in the template.

Then, while running the application, I've encountered one of the most obscure unexpected behaviors: All the properties were set, except for the bounded `Center` (i.e. I got a bunch of big orange red cubes all centered at the origin). More strangely, when I've set a breakpoint just before the function returned to check the properties, they were all set correctly, including `Center`, even if the output is wrong!

## Conclusion

Did I miss that WPF really provides a way to bind a collection to a particular 3D class? Or did anyone found a solution on the helix toolkit side?